# Inheritance: dynamic derived class members vs static derrived class members

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, c++14

The purpose is to implement a base class : vector_base...

I have a few misconceptions on how to go about creating a base class for the two vector classes outlined below.

first: Should the base class have a constructor per derived class and a default constructor? or is there a way to call the base constructor to complete the derived in this scenario ...

```
class three: public two
{
  private:

    double z;

  public:

    three(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0)
      : two(x, y), // call two(double, double) to initialize x & y
      z(z)

    // ...
};
```

second: Should the base class have two sets of coordinates (x, y, z) static vs dynamic (of type pointer)?

third: How do accessors and mutators work in each case; is there any reason to consider keywords: virtual and override?

Basically I do not understand how to achieve polymorphism if the data members are of type double and type double*

```
class vector_static 
{
  private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

  public:

    vector_static(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0)
      : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    vector_static(const vector_static& copy)
      : x(copy.x), y(copy.y), z(copy.z) {}

    ~vector_static() 
    { 
      std::cout << "vector_static::~vector_static() " << std::endl; 
};

class vector_dynamic
{
  private:
    double* x = nullptr;
    double* y = nullptr;
    double* z = nullptr;

  public:

    vector_dynamic(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0)
      : x {new double (x)},
      y {new double (y)},
      z {new double (z)}
    {
    }

    vector_dynamic(const vector_dynamic& copy)
      : x{new double (copy.get_x() )},
      y{new double (copy.get_y() )},
      z{new double (copy.get_z() )}
    {
    }

    ~vector_dynamic()
    {
      std::cout << "\nvector_dynamic::~vector_dynamic()" << std::endl;
      delete x;
      delete y;
      delete z;
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the point of `vector_dynamic`? There doesn't seem to be any reason to use pointers there.

Comment: maybe he was mixing the vector container to his vector coords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector_static` and `vector_dynamic` are not related, you can't use them polymorphically. They would need to have a common base class that defines virtual functions that can be called to access the coordinates. Then you would override those methods in each derived class to get or set the coordinates; one would access the members directly, the other would dereference the pointers.

```
class vector_generic {
public:
    virtual double getX();
    virtual void setX(double);
    ...
}

class vector_static : public vector_generic {
public:
    double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    double setX(double newX) {
        x = newX;
    }
    ...
}

class vector_dynamic : public vector_generic {
public:
    double getX() {
        return *x;
    }
    double setX(double newX) {
        *x = newX;
    }
    ...
}
```

With this, you can then do:

```
vector_generic *vec1 = new vector_static();
vector_generic *vec2 = new vector_dynamic();
cout << vec1->getX() << vec2->getX() << '\n';
```

Comment: question, this (the name `vector`) won't have conflict with `std::vector` (if it is not "used")?

Comment: If you don't have `using namespace std;` there won't be any conflict. But I've updated my answer to use a better name.